# How to remove the default "variable name= " label, and instead retain only value of variable

Tags: r, recur

I want to have cleaner names for the Y axes in my stratified graph below

Eg: Gender variable called "gender2", has two levels "Male", "Female". Upon plotting,

```
AGsex=Recur(exityrs,id,as.integer(anyhpv))~gender2
plotEvents(AGsex,xlab="Time in years",base_size=5,)
```

i get [Recur object of subjects followup trajectories in study, with a reccurent event marked by a green dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piABd.png)
I would like the stratified y axes to say "Male" and "female" only..would this be a feature of the plot function? I.e is there a easy way of doing this in the plot code itself instead of having to create temporary data frames etc

Comment: what package is this? can you share sample data?

Comment: I am using the Recur and reda packages, teh data structure is longitudinal where each participant can have multiple rows, one row per event, where the final row is time from last event observed until censor.

Comment: There is no `Recur` package on CRAN. Do you mean you're using `reda::Recur()`?

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes listing all non-base packages (I think it's just `reda` here), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality seems to be hard coded into the `plotEvents()` function so I don't think there's a built-in option for this. However, since it returns a `ggplot` object, you can modify the facetting layer and edit the labels:

```r
# minimal example
library(reda)
library(reReg)
gender2 <- rep(c("Male", "Female"), 5)
ex1 <- Recur(1:10)~gender2
g = plotEvents(ex1) 

# function to remove the gender2 part of the label from a string
rm_label <- function(string, to_rm = "gender2 = ") {
  string <- stringr::str_remove(string, to_rm)
  string
}

# remake the plot and add your own facets
g + 
  facet_wrap(~gender2, ncol = 1, strip.position = "left",
             labeller = labeller(gender2 = rm_label))
```

gives:

[image: plot]